# Make disabled view look like it was enabled. ANDROID

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

Is there any way I can make a Switch View not turn gray when is disabled?, I want it to keep the same colors for both text and the toggle element as it was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

That would required providing a custom style to the switch button based on its state.